# BIND failing to query external DNS records

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, samba

Unfortunately, I'm an amateur sys admin and can't figure out what is going on with BIND (9.8). We have two old Samba servers that we use as our active directory domain controllers and therefore they are also our DNS servers. Today all of a sudden, all our external DNS requests started failing, while the internal ones still work. For example (*all IP addresses removed for security*):

```
adminlocal@srvdc2:~$ dig +trace +additional google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> +trace +additional google.com
;; global options: +cmd
.                       19357   IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       19357   IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       19357   IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       19357   IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       19357   IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       19357   IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       19357   IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       19357   IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       19357   IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       19357   IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       19357   IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       19357   IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       19357   IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
;; Received 228 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx#53(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) in 123019 ms

.                       3600    IN      NS      FWDR-166.FWDR-35.FWDR-80.FWDR-91.
.                       3600    IN      NS      FWDR-133.FWDR-35.FWDR-80.FWDR-91.
FWDR-166.FWDR-35.FWDR-80.FWDR-91. 3600 IN A     91.80.35.166
FWDR-133.FWDR-35.FWDR-80.FWDR-91. 3600 IN A     91.80.35.133
;; BAD (HORIZONTAL) REFERRAL
dig: couldn't get address for 'FWDR-166.FWDR-35.FWDR-80.FWDR-91': no more
```

However, the internet works, and so I can ping Google's server just fine :

```
adminlocal@srvdc2:~$ ping 216.58.208.174
PING 216.58.208.174 (216.58.208.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 216.58.208.174: icmp_req=1 ttl=53 time=48.9 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.208.174: icmp_req=2 ttl=53 time=49.4 ms
```

I can also do DNS requests via another server :

```
root@srvdc2:/etc/bind# dig @1.1.1.1 google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> @1.1.1.1 google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 34033
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             96      IN      A       172.217.21.78

;; Query time: 61 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Mar 27 17:42:22 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 44
```

Furthermore, in `/var/log/messages` I see that `named` is producing a bunch of errors all the time :

```
root@srvdc2:~# tail /var/log/messages
Mar 27 17:26:13 srvdc2 rsyslogd-2177: imuxsock begins to drop messages from pid 2105 due to rate-limiting
Mar 27 17:26:17 srvdc2 rsyslogd-2177: imuxsock lost 55 messages from pid 2105 due to rate-limiting
Mar 27 17:26:26 srvdc2 rsyslogd-2177: imuxsock begins to drop messages from pid 2105 due to rate-limiting
Mar 27 17:26:29 srvdc2 rsyslogd-2177: imuxsock lost 68 messages from pid 2105 due to rate-limiting
...
root@srvdc2:~# ps -ef | grep 2105
bind      2105     1  1 17:11 ?        00:00:16 /usr/sbin/named -u bind
```

Of course, internet works on the machines if I force the DNS to point to an external DNS server, but then they lose access to internal resources. Does anyone have an idea what I could do to find out more about the problem?

Thank you sincerely for any help you can offer.

Comment: What is this `FWDR-166.FWDR-35.FWDR-80.FWDR-91.` stuff and does this strange referral response for the root zone relate to any known configuration in your environment? (The associated IPs seem to be owned by Vodafone Italy, if that rings any bells for someone familiar with this environment.)

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist I honestly don't know what that `FWDR` stuff is. However, those two IP addresses are the 3rd and 4th DNS server listed in the upstream gateway. I'm going to remove them to see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I don't quite understand why but the problem came from the upstream gateway. It had 4 DNS servers listed (2 given by the ISP and 2 backups) but apparently the two backup DNS servers were being used by BIND (which I imagine is working in relay mode...?). Thus, for whatever reason, these two external DNS servers stopped working and so every external DNS request passing by the local BIND server was failing when it tried to send the request higher up.

The solution: I removed the reference to the two servers and replaced them with Cloudflare DNS.

Thank you to all who spent time on this question!